# Using Vector of pointers to Objects which have pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a loop which adds pointers to a vector;

```
vector<Material *> materials;
```

and my Material class has 4 attributes :

```
int id;
float *ambiance;
float *diffuse;
```

in my loop :

```
while(input_read_from_the_file !=NULL){
int id=someval1;
float x[2]={someval2,someval3};
float y[2]={someval4,someval5};
materials.push_back(new Material(id,x,y));
}
```

When I read my materials vector in a for loop I see that ids are different but ambiance and diffuse are same for all the elements.Thats probably because it uses the same pointer in the while loop but I couldnt find an alternative.What should be the best  approach here?
Thanks

Comment: Your pointers point to variables that are local to the while loop. This is undefined behaviour. Why not store arrays or vectors instead of pointers?

Comment: Should I use arrays instead of pointers in my class?
instead of float* ambiance; float ambiance[3];

Comment: @Emrah is there is a reasonable and *known* fixed number of them you'd be crazy *not* to store them as a declared array. There is no need to store them dynamically if that is the case. If there is such a need, use a vector instead.

Comment: Thank you very much it solved my problem.I am not crazy but a beginner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to avoid pointers as much as I can.
Let's start with your vector. Why does it need to be `vector<Material*>` and not `vector<Material>`?
Unless `Material` is an inherited class, you can use a vector of `Material` objects instead of pointers.
That way, you don't need the destructor of the class that has `vector<Material*>` to iterate and destroy each of them (by using `shared_ptr`, you can avoid this too).

Now, as mentioned in the comments, the problem is that `Material` uses pointers for the `ambiance` and `diffuse` members. No reason for that too. 
Technically, you want it to be `Vector3` or `Vector4` when you're writing a renderer or material system, but lets go with `float[2]` instead.

C++11 (0x) has cool move semantics that you can use to avoid the creation of a temporary object (since we're going to push an object into the vector and without move semantics, a temporary object is created while doing so)

So, your code looks like:

```
class Material {
int id;
float ambiance[2]; // you really ought to use Vector2 instead. pointers are evil.
float diffuse[2];

Material (const int _id, const float _amb[], const float _dif[]) : id(_id) {
   ambiance[0] = _amb[0]; ambiance[1] = _amb[1]; // actual copy is made
   diffuse[0]  = _dif[0]; diffuse[1]  = _dif[1]; 
}
}

-----
vector<Material> materials;

while(input_read_from_the_file !=NULL){
   int id    = someval1;
   float x[2]= {someval2,someval3};
   float y[2]= {someval4,someval5};
   materials.emplace_back(Material(id,x,y)); // or even materials.emplace_back(id, x, y);
}
```